# How to aggregate KStream to list of fixed size in a specific timeframe?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, boot

Consider this KStream:

```
KStream<String, String> inputStream = streamsBuilder.stream("kafka-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
Materialized<String, List<String>, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> with = Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), STRING_LIST_SERDE);

KStream<Windowed<String>, List<String>> outputStream = inputStream
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
            .aggregate(
                    ArrayList::new,
                    (key, string, aggregate) -> {
                        aggregate.add(string);
                        return aggregate;
                    }, with)
            .toStream();
```

`outputStream` will aggregate all the messages from `inputStream` info an array of messages for the defined timeframe.
Now, in addition, I want to aggregate the messages up to a specific limit, say until the list is no longer than 50 in size.
If the list has become larger than 50 during the aggregation, I want to somehow split it to additional list.

Basically, the output I wish to achieve is to get an array of messages up to a limit by size (of 50 for instance) and up to a specific timeframe, whichever comes first.

What do I missing here in order to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect to produce multiple events under the same key in the aggregation? So if you had 150 elements to aggregate you'd expect 3 events each with 50 elements in the list, all with the same key?

Comment: yes exactly what you said

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert your `KTable` to `KStream` and execute `flatMapValues` to split the list, something like this (code in Kotlin):

```kotlin
val s = streamsBuilder.stream("kafka-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
val output = s
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
    .aggregate({ mutableListOf() }, { k: String, str: String, agg: List<String> -> agg.plus(str) })
    .toStream()
    .flatMapValues { strList -> strList.chunked(50) }
```

that would mean however that you load the whole aggregated list into memory - might or might not be a concern, depending on the list size and your memory settings, but it's definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: I will check your solution and update if it succeeded or not, thanks!